# PHPExcel DATE Formate

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

How to type date format in open excel

```
foreach($detail->result() as $data) {
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow($kol+1, $bar, $data->t_spk_id, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
    $sheet->setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow($kol+2, $bar, date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($data->t_spk_respontime)), PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);

    $bar++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There it needs to be formatted the field and the value too on writing to excel object:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($excel_field)->getNumberFormat()
     ->setFormatCode('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(
     $excel_field,PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(convert_date( $datetime )))
```

On reading then must to format again back to the php date format from the excel representation:

```
$val = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue()));
```